# Multiple DB inserts even when detecting if it exists?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a php script that listens for $_POST input, and inserts into my table which can then be read in my Wordpress plugin and displayed to the admin. Given how people submit forms multiple times, I check the database to see if the entry already exists, using a unique invoice number that is sent in the form.

My code is:

```
global $wpdb; 
$submits_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'submits_table';
$invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
$exists = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $submits_table WHERE `invoice` = $invoice" );
    if ( $exists == NULL ) {

        $wpdb->insert(
            $submits_table,
                array(
                'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
                'ip_address' => $_POST['ipaddress'],
                'invoice' => $invoice
            ),
            array(
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s'
            )
        );

}
```

The problem is that *every single submission* gets inserted, regardless  whether the invoice number already exists or not. I've tried this same code on a different page from the Admin panel and it works okay; it's only when it's set as a listener for the front end submissions does it not work right.

I'm ripping my hair out. Any ideas as to why `get_row()` is returning NULL every time on the front end but not the admin?

EDIT: `invoice` is alphanumeric, so it's `varchar`.

Comment: is invoice column VARCHAR or INT

Comment: Restricting inserts based on uniqueness (whether it exists) is done by placing `unique` constraint on the database level, you don't do this from PHP. Reason why you don't do it from PHP Is exactly what you're experiencing - PHP can't enforce uniqueness, or any other language for that matter. Only database can do it.

Answer (score 0):

[`wpdb::get_row`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/)

> Return
>
> (array|object|null|void) Database query result in format specified by
>   $output or **null on failure**

so , it will not be a proper way to check for existents with `null`

instead, check the count of the returned result:

```
if (count($exists) > 0)
```

Comment: `count()` doesn't work either - at least, it works properly testing duplicates on the admin page but not in the front end listener where I need it.

Comment: what's the output of `print_r($exists);` ?